# Extracting timestamp field in Oracle vs MySQL from Grails-Groovy

Tags: oracle, datetime, grails, groovy

I am using grails/groovy, and from my controller I am currently doing this for retrieving field from Mysql table containing datetime field

```
SimpleDateFormat Sformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String format_datenow = Sformat.format(new Date());
String format_dateprevious = Sformat.format(new Date() -31);

 String markerCalcQuery =
            "select sum(trans_cnt) as t_cnt, location from map2_data where fdate between '"+format_dateprevious+"' and '"+format_dateprevious+"' and res_id = "+res_id+"  group by map2_data.location";
res_row=gurculsql.rows(markerCalcQuery);
```

The above query fails on Oracle11g with error

> ORA-01843: not a valid month.

The error I feel is because MySQL stores date in this format: `2011-12-28 02:58:26` and Oracle stores date like this: `28-DEC-11 02.58.26.455000000 PM`

How do I make the code generalised, one way is to make the database in Oracle store the date in the same format which I am thinking the way to handle this rather than from the code. If yes, how to change date format in the Oracle db?

Can I specify the format in the grails domain class for `map2_data` so that no matter what database it is we will have the datetime in the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, dates have their own type, they aren't strings. If you have a string, you should convert it to a date using the `TO_DATE` function.

```
String format_datenow = "TO_DATE('" + Sformat.format(new Date()) + "', 'YYYY-MM-DD')";
```

To make it work also in MySQL, you can create a stored function named `TO_DATE` that just returns its first argument.

Comment: Hi, we cannot use a stored function or procedure in our implementation. That makes this solution only specific to oracle, is there a generic way to handle dates is both mysql and oracle.

Comment: Question still remains because I cannot use a stored function or procedure in mysql..for my implementation...is there some other way to make it generalised?

Comment: In your Groovy code, write a function formatDate(str), which will return either its argument or "TO_DATE(...", according to the DB. You'll need a library of those functions anyway, if you are issuing direct queries, because that's not the only way those DBs differ.

Answer (score 2):

For several reasons (one being to code database independent - which is basically what you'd need ;-)), it is better to avoid creating SQL statements in your code. Try to use the Grails criteria DSL, e.g. something like

```
def criteria = YourDomainObject.createCriteria()
criteria.get {
    between ('fdate', new Date()-31, new Date())
    projections {
        sum('trans_cnt')
        groupProperty('location')
    }
}
```

(ontested, but should help you get started).
If for some reason you can't use the criteria API, try the fallback to HQL (Hibernate Query Language). I'd always try to avoid to write plain SQL.

Comment: How Do I have an Alias for sum(trans_cnt)? could not find an example anywhere